# Using an array of values in Factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently I have a factory that is using a json file wrapped in a $http.get request. While not ideal, this works for testing. I'm needing to test the same solution within a SharePoint environment, but json files are not allowed. Ultimately this will be connected to a web api call.

How can I specify the json values within a factory, to allow for testing?

```
(function() {
var personalViewFactory = function($http) {

    var factory = {};

    factory.getCustomers = function() {
        return $http.get('relationshiptracker.json');
    };



    return factory;
};

personalViewFactory.$inject = ['$http'];

angular.module('customersApp').factory('customersFactory', 
                                       personalViewFactory);

}());
```

Example of json

```
[
{
"Segment":"Trading",
"Title":"Narima Ajam ",
"Role":"Oil and Shipping Competency Center Manager ",
"Last Meeting Date":"1/1/2000",
"nextmeetingowner":"",
"CreatedDate":"9/14/2014",
"Modified":"9/14/2014",
"primaryaccountability":"Ajay Buti ",
"otherltEngaged":"Aylin Korkmaz, Carolyn Williams, Karthik Chandrasekar",
"upcomingdate":""
},
{
"Segment":"Upstream",
"Title":"Alison Kenney",
"Role":"IM/IT Manager - The Bridge; (NOLA) - The Bridge",
"Last Meeting Date":"8/5/2014",
"nextmeetingowner":"",
"CreatedDate":"1/2/2000",
"Modified":"2/15/2014",
"primaryaccountability":"Arnold",
"otherltEngaged":"Yero",
"upcomingdate":""
},]
```

Comment: This seems too simple so I must not be understanding your requirement as all I see for you to do is make a var, assign your JSON to it and then return it in your getCustomers call. Possibly wrap it in a promise depending on what your client code is doing with it.

Comment: I'm probably over complicating an easy problem. I'm trying this, but I'm missing something. http://jsfiddle.net/sharepointjason/zcrfty78/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place your JSON on a variable in your factory and close over it in your functions.

http://plnkr.co/edit/gWklBTEZWqxPzQjhV19D?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="myCtrl">

    {{myData}}

    <script>
      var app=angular.module("app",[]);

      app.factory("data",function($http){
        var data = [{name:'Bob'},{name:'Amy'}];
        return{
          getData : function(){
            return data;
          }
        }
      });

      app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope,data){

        $scope.myData = data.getData();

      });

      angular.bootstrap(document,["app"]);

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is a beast of an application I inherited. How would I wrap it up? http://embed.plnkr.co/IDvXmzRdwIgXsfKMoiOI/preview